# Two or more ReadSideProcessors per service in Lagom

Tags: java, solr, lagom

Is it possible to register two or more ReadSideProcessors per service in Lagom, like this:

```
@Inject
public BlogServiceImpl(
        PersistentEntityRegistry persistentEntityRegistry,
        ReadSide readSide) {
  this.persistentEntityRegistry = persistentEntityRegistry;

  readSide.register(CassandraBlogEventProcessor.class);
  readSide.register(SolrBlogEventProcessor.class);
}
```

Comment: Short answer is yes. Did you try it and have some problem?

Comment: No, I have my 'standard' Cassandra ReadSide implemented and didn't wanted to go into the Solr ReadSide without knowing if it is OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can register as many read-side processors as you need. Note that each one will consume events independently of the others, so you should take care not to assume anything about the order of processing between different read-side processors.